# Merging VSTS Git Repo to another VSTS Git Repo

Tags: git, azure-devops

We are working with a 3rd party development company and sharing their VSTS Git Repository for Source Control. As a Dev team we are all new to Git having worked with TFS for many years.

They are coming to the end of their contract and I have copied their Repo to a VSTS account we control so I can generate automated builds.

Migrating was simple using the builtin VSTS migration tool. This [short video from Microsoft MVP Mohamed Radwan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4P7QW1C4bRo) shows exactly how to do this.

I have setup a number of transforms on our VSTS repo but as they are still developing on theirs, I want to be able to merge any changes from their GIT Repo to ours without having to resort to manual processes.

I could pull their changes locally, change the origin to my Git Repo and then push but ideally I like a less manual approach if possible, especiually as they are checking in multiple times per day.

If we assume their Repo is **Git_Repo_1** and mine is **Git_Repo_2**, is there a way I can merge changes from Git_Repo_1 -> Git_Repo_2 while maintaining any changes in Git_Repo_2?

Any help is most appreciated.

JGilmartin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep!

Git is meant to be entirely decentralised so you can copy things across repos and across "[remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)".

So let's say they are on your internal Git repo `Git_Repo_2` and you want to look at changes in `Git_Repo_1`. You can execute `git add remote contractors https://org.visualstudio.com/_git/git_repo_2` where now contract will be the upstream of your contractors repository.

You can now push and pull from two remotes. By default Git_Repo_2 will be on the `origin` remote.

So to merge something from Git_Repo_1 into Git_Repo_2 you can execute `git merge contractors/branch` while you're checked out into the desired branch to merge into in Git_Repo_2 (`git checkout master` for example)

Further reading: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/